# How to delete a record from a json column using laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I have a jsonb column that contains data of a user. I have been able to store and update information of that json column. But now I need to delete a particular data. for instance if a user clicks a delte button it will delete that index data.

```
"work": [
{
"id": "da4582be-2075-11e9-99db-08002718287a",
"info": "work",
"company": "Augnitive",
"working_to": "2021-05-12",
"designation": "Software Engineer",
"working_from": "2019-11-15",
"responsibilities": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
}
],
"contact": [],
"personal": [
{
"id": "a8cba4a2-2075-11e9-9b58-08002718287a",
"bday": "1993-07-21",
"info": "personal",
"blood": "B(+VE)",
"gender": "Male"
}
],
"education": [
{
"id": "b1bab9ee-206c-11e9-a640-08002718287a",
"info": "education",
"edu_type": "SSC 1234",
"institute": "PGJHS 2",
"graduation": "2012"
},
{
"id": "b2842910-2075-11e9-a835-08002718287a",
"info": "education",
"edu_type": "HSC",
"institute": "PGC",
"graduation": "2012"
}
]
}
```

Here is the blade file form where I am trying to send which the index of that data

```
@foreach($profile['education'] as  $index => $education)
    <table class="table bio-table">

            <a href="#delete"
            data-toggle="modal"
            class="deleteNews btn-danger margin-left float-right"
            data-route="{{ route('home.destroy',$education) }}"
            data-target="#deleteEducation"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>



**Modal for this :** 

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteEducation">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete Page</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>Are you sure?</h2><br>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.deleteEducation').click(function () {
        $('#deleteEducation form').attr('action', $(this).data('route'));
    });
});
```

Now how can i delete that data ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , if you can manipulate JSON like this, but perhaps its easier to write the JSON new without the data you want to delete?

Comment: that's the issue I don't know how to do that .